# Embedding a local video into a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, youtube

**How to embed a local video into a UIView?**

There is a similar question here: [Embeding youtube video into a UIView/UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700759/embeding-youtube-video-into-a-uiview-uiwebview) 
however, it is in obj-c and uses youtube.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use AVPlayer

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let filepath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "qidong", ofType: "mp4")
        let fileURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filepath!)


        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)


        let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        avPlayerController.player = avPlayer
        avPlayerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)

//  hide show control
        avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
// play video

        avPlayerController.player?.play()
        self.view.addSubview(avPlayerController.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I want to play the video in a UIVIEW

Comment: which is called 'vidview'"

Comment: i want to play it without controls

Comment: Thank you, sir, (my akhi from cairo ;) ) !