# Cannot get AVPlayerLayer on iOS13.x by Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios13

I'm making an iOS app with objective-c.
Please tell me how to fix AVPlayerView in iOS13.x environment.

ViewController.m write

```
AVPlayerLayer* layer = (AVPlayerLayer*)self.videoView.layer;
```

VideoView contains AVPlayerView

AVPlayerView.m write

```
#import "AVPlayerView.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation AVPlayerView

+(Class)layerClass{
    return AVPlayerLayer.class;
}

@end
```

The layerClass method is not called for some reason.
Also, the class returned by (AVPlayerLayer *) self.videoView.layer
AVPresentationVontainerViewLayer.
I want an AVPlayerView class.
How should i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    AVPlayerViewController *AVPlayerVc = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    AVPlayerVc.player = player;
    if (AVPlayerVc) {
        [self presentViewController:AVPlayerVc animated:YES completion:^{
            [player play];
        }];
    }
```

Swift Version:

```
 let player = AVPlayer(url: YOUR_URL)
 let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
 playerController.player = player
 present(playerController, animated: true) {
         player.play()
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
The error has disappeared.
However, when the movie is played back, the sound is played but the video is not played.  
Do I need to change my storyboard connection?

Comment: Yes i think the video is playing in another view

Comment: Thank you.I want to display a video player in an existing AVPlayerView instead of creating a new one. Is this possible?

Comment: i 'don't understand what you want exactly

Comment: Sorry...Until now, UIView was installed and AVPlayerView was set as Custom Class.
And it is going to play a video with the UIView.
However, the above code will play full screen on the video player.
I want to display a video in UIView.

Comment: take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653779/how-to-play-a-video-in-uiview-swift